# OpenLayers 3 Graticule - Wrapped Maps

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I wanted to display the graticule on my map using Openlayers 3 in the same way provided by Openlayers 2 (http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/jsdoc/examples/graticule.html), i.e. having the graticule showing on every version of a wrapped map.

Here, the graticule is only displayed on the first/centered version :

```
var graticule = new ol.Graticule({
        maxLines:10,
          // the style to use for the lines, optional.
          strokeStyle: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.9)',
          })
        });
```

(jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/tlebras/gb33annw/2/)

Two questions :

1 - Is there a way to display the graticule on every version of a wrapped map?

2 - As you can see on the openlayers2 exemple, labels are shown. 
Is there a way to show some labels on the graticule with ol3? There is no mention in the documentation.